# SQL SSMS: changed 'allow nulls' design, now can't switch back (`cannot insert the value NULL into column`)

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ssms, primary-key

I'm working in a dev `SQL` database within `SSMP`.

We've got a junction table, `jnc_roles_users`, which pulls values from two lookup tables: `lu_roles` and `lu_users`.

Initially, all but one column in the junction table had the `Allow Nulls` checkbox checked. I then went into the design editor and checked all the boxes - got the alert that this will affect the two lookup tables, and saved the changes successfully.

Now, I want to switch back to the original table design of nothing allowing nulls except one column. But SSMS is no longer allowing me to uncheck the `Allow Nulls` box for one of the fields. Ironically, no problem unchecking our 'ID' primary key. It's our 'pseudo' primary key 'roleUserID' that I can't change back. When I try to uncheck 'Allow Nulls' for it and save, I get the alert:

`'jnc_roles_users' table
- Unable to modify table.

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'roleUserID', table 'jnc_roles_users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.`

This seems counterintuitive because the column is currently stuck at 'Allow Nulls', yet this popup is telling me it can't accept nulls.

lu_roles and lu_users was saved successfully, but not jnc_roles_users which is the only table which contains 'roleUserID'.

The `roleUserID` column isn't technically a primary key - but we're considering it 'like' one as it does take unique values that we set. For certain reasons we're considering this column as a sort of primary key - something to do w/ database backups in different locations and how the regular ID pk might get duplicated incorrectly in different environments, so we needed a second pseudo pk of `roleUserID`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Has data been added to the table with a NULL since you changed Allow NULL in the table designer?

Comment: Bingo - this was it...was doing some test POSTs and didn't realize it inserted a null. If you want to write as an answer, I'll mark as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that some new data with a NULL value was added to the table between the time you changed Allow NULL in the designer and the time you went to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ALTER TABLE -

```
ALTER TABLE jnc_role_users
ALTER COLUMN roleUserID NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
```

Change NVARCHAR(50) to the data type the roleUserID column uses

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little unclear on the question - change NOT NULL to NULL if you want to force the column to allow nulls, leave as NOT NULL if you want the column to not allow nulls.